# Is there a copy constructor for Map Fields in Python Protocol Buffers?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

[Python Generated Code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#map-fields) explains most use-cases of protobuf [map fields](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#map-fields) in Python but not how to copy one map to another.

Given simple map

```
message Src {
    map<string, string> properties = 1;
    ...
}

message Dst {
    map<string, string> properties = 1;
    ...
}
```

You cannot assign a value to an embedded message field, so there's no doing:

```
# Will not work.
dst = Dst()
dst.properties = src.properties
```

Nor is there an implementation of [CopyFrom](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.message.Message-class#CopyFrom) since map is not itself a message, it's a field within a message.

```
# Will not work.
dst = Dst()
dst.properties.CopyFrom(src.properties)
```

I also can't copy the entire message since I only want the map.

```
# Copies unwanted fields!
dst = Dst()
dst.CopyFrom(src)
```

I hope I don't have to iterate over all keys and assign one-by-one!

```
# Iterate over map keys
for key in src.properties:
    dst.properties[key] = src.properties[key]
```

Comment: Did you try MergeFrom? I'm curious to learn what worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the maps' values are simple types, `dst.properties.update(src.properties)` should work. However, if you have a map with Message-type values, e.g.:

```
message Prop {
  optional string value = 1;
  optional bool is_public = 2;
}

message Src {
    map<string, Prop> properties = 1;
    ...
}

message Dst {
    map<string, Prop> properties = 1;
    ...
}
```

then `.update` (or any type of direct assignment) will throw:

```
ValueError: Direct assignment of submessage not allowed
```

Instead, you'll have to do something like:

```
for k, v in src.properties.items():
  dst.properties[k].CopyFrom(v)
```

Answer (score 4):

Map fields in python protobuf generated code operate pretty similarly to python dicts, so you can use .update() to copy over:

```
dst.properties.update(src.properties)
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work: ValueError: Direct assignment of submessage not allowed

Comment: This solution worked for me, my map is <string, int32>.  Perhaps you have other issues with your types?